# Wordpress permalink

Tags: wordpress

I have been having a few problems with my blog and was hoping someone on here may be able to help me out, i have set it up so the the blog is not on the home page but sits on a different page e.g. /blog/.

The permalinks for posts were set to /%category%/%postname%/ and were displaying as so site.com/category/postname, i wanted it to keep the blog prefix (site.com/blog/category/postname) so i changed the permalink structure to /blog/%category%/%postname%/ to work.

Now i want to remove the category base, i have done this by putting /. in the field but this removes /blog/ from my permalink. Is there any way around this?

Sorry if i have missed out any crucial information, let me know and i will add it!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-no-category-base/

Answer (score 0):

You can learn more about this plugin http://tutslog.com/tutorials/plugin-wordpress-supermalink-139.html if you want add dynamic permalink content

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't post link-only answers, they go stale when the link dies. You could improve your answer by adding an excerpt of the linked article (use the "edit" option for this). Good luck!